# Mask URL path on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to mask the following Route

```
get '/products/1' => 'products#show', :as => "map"
```

as hotels/2/map inside my Application, but I'm having no luck. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, as this is already nested inside the Hotels resource. I'm automatically creating two products when the hotel is created, so 1 will be the Map and 2 will be the App.

```
resources :hotels do

    resources :contacts
    resources :products

    get '/products/1' => 'products#show', :as => "map"

end
```

Comment: Do you need to have the product ID fixed as `1`?

Comment: @RPinel Yes. Still stuck with this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you've got will create hotel_map_path at /hotels/:hotel_id/products/1(.:format). If you instead want map_path without the hotel_prefix, you need to move the map route out of the hotel namespace, like so:

```
resources :hotels do
  resources :contacts
  resources :products
end
get 'hotels/:hotel_id/products/1' => 'hotels/products#show', :as => "map"
```

Hope that helps

**edit**

I'm gonna revise my suggestion. What you're trying to do will create a dependency between the routes and the details of db storage (the id), which feels wrong. Instead, I'd suggest pushing that dependency into the active_record model, which is the only class that should be responsible for knowing about how Hotels and Products are persisted.

So, your route would be something like:

```
resources :hotels do
  member do
   get :map
  end
  resources :contacts
  resources :products
end
```

which should give you

```
/hotels/:id/map
```

in the hotels_controller you'll have

```
def map
  @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
  @map = @hotel.location_map
end
```

and in the Hotel model:

```
def map
  products.location_map
end
```

and in the Product model:

```
def location_map
 ...
end
```

or add a scope instead.

It's more lines to get the same routing effect, but less brittle.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but your solution has not worked. I'm looking to get /hotels/:id/map to route to hotels/:id/products/1

Comment: I made a small edit - what you should get is hotels/products/show, with hotel_id = :hotel_id and :id = 1. Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: Close, but no cigar. I'm looking for hotels/:id/map to bring up _the_ product that belongs to the hotel, and has an :product_type of 0, as there will only ever be two products associated with each hotel and these are created at the same time as the hotel. This all works, and I can get to these pages via the default routes.

Comment: Then I'd definitely suggest the approach in my updated answer - add a verb to the routes but don't hardcode it to a db id. Let the Hotel or Product models take care of that part.

Comment: I have followed your method, but when I try and call @map on the map.html.erb page, I'm getting NoMethodError

Comment: (FYI I've updated my answer to change the method name, so as not to confuse it with the standard map method)  Did you define the locatio_map method on the hotel class? In the console, does Hotel.first.location_map work?